# How can I dynamically set zoom in leaflet when in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, leaflet

I have an asp.net app with an iframe in it on a tab in the markup.  The content of the iframe is a Leaflet based map display.  The markup:

```
    <div id="tabMapDisplay" class="tab-pane row container">
        <div id="divMapDisplay" runat="server" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 fieldset-border-bg-defaults">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe id="ifrMap" runat="server" allowfullscreen="true" class="embed-responsive-item" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The source url for the Leaflet display is a parameterized url set in the code behind based on data for the overall display.  Works great, shows the map with the target as desired.  Except if the target is a very large feature on the map it then shows the display and the target feature can stretch beyond the boundary visible in the iframe so that part of the feature is hidden until the user zooms out on the map.

I decided to try having the Leaflet app adjust the zoom level dynamically so that larger features will fit when viewed in an iframe.  When viewed straight up in the browser they show just fine.  Here's what I've got trying to determine the zoom level so far (I've cut out all the experimental bits I've been attempting all day):

```
        function inIframe() {
            try {
                return window.self !== window.top;
            } catch (e) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        function optimalZoomLevel(boundsZoom) {
            if (boundsZoom < zl) {
                zl = boundsZoom;
            }

            if (inIframe()) {

                zl = zl - 1;
            }

            return zl;
        }
```

zl is set to a default zoom level value as a starting point.  Everything is fine as I said when directly in the browser.  But in the iframe (the detection function inIframe works correctly), once this code knows it the page is in an iframe no matter what I do I cannot seem to get the height and width of the containing frame.  Everything I've tried comes up either 0, undefined, or the dimensions of the browser window not the iframe.  I've tried using a number of different options I've found by searching but so far nothing more than 0 or undefined for the width value I'm looking for.   I figure if I can know the width then I can adjust the zoom level to something appropriate so the whole of the larger candidate marker/shapes show in the iframe.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Why not have the code in the iframe automatically zoom out by itself, since you have troubles determining its size from the parent?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do dynamically.  I could just generically zoom out all the time to a certain level but then on 95% of the display targets (these are pedestrian and bicycling project candidates) will be so distant the user has to zoom in to see anything useful.  If I can determine the iframe dimensions then I can use the feature extent to set the zoom so the whole thing fits in the case of really large ones.